# Syntax error: in the "IF" block with Python

Tags: python-3.x, syntax, syntax-error

```
if new.upper() == "C":
            first()
        try:
            a, b, c = re.split(r"(\s+)", new)
        except ValueError:
            return
```

> The syntaxs error occures to the colon behind "C". if new.upper() == "C":
>   What can i do to fix this problem?

Comment: Are you sure that your spacing is correct? In the question, it is not.

Answer (score 1):

Your indentation is incorrect. It should look like.

```
if new.upper() == "C":
    first()
    try:
        a, b, c = re.split(r"(\s+)", new)
    except ValueError:
        pass
```

Additionally use `pass` instead of `return` unless that snippet of code is inside a function. Because return can only be used inside a function.

Edit:
Added in the correct indentation points

Comment: You indentation is also off man. But yeah that's the main problem that user is having. Weird to see a throw catch without the base syntax down though. May not be the issue I think.

Comment: Oh wow. Thanks for that. Didn't even notice. Very awkward there.

Comment: No worries. I have a habit of messing indentation up when pasting to this site myself. Things don't transfer that well sometimes. I still do find it odd that using exceptions he messed up indentation, maybe just came from cpp over or something I guess. That's a much more 'advanced' concept than line formatting to me but it happens I guess.